# coredns CrashLoopBackOff due to Error during parsing: Unknown directive 'ready'

Tags: kubernetes

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pyi8V.png)

coredns CrashLoopBackOff due to Error during parsing: Unknown directive 'ready'

Comment: Hello, please read SO article about asking a question: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

You need to provide more details about your environment. Its local, On-Prem? What version of Kubernetes are you using. Its Kubeadm, Minikube, MicroK8s, GKE, etc? How to reproduce this issue. It happend after you applied some config or its since beginning? Can you provide log output `kubectl logs <pod-name> -n <namespace>`. Also you should avoid posting images and use text in question.

Answer (score -1):

You can easily understand the problem by using command

```
kubectl describe pods coredns-85xxxxx -n kube-system.
```